# BMS balance lead fuses for 2A active balancer

Tags: batteries, fuses, bms

I am building a 16S pack of lf280k LiFePo4 cells. I will be using JK BMS capable of 2A balance current and will be connecting to each cell with wires with fuses. I assume 3A will be sufficient.

Do I put a fuse in each of the 17 wires or only 16?

One site selling premade harness warned not to fuse the 1st wire or "damage will occur". This was for a different BMS which should not matter.

I can't imagine how a fuse can cause damage unless excessive current fuses it. Maybe that harness had the 1st line used for both balancing and power.

Please advise.
Thank you

Comment: Which 16? All but ground/minus of bottom cell?

Comment: That is the question. I don't see why I shouldn't have fuses on all 17 wires. The site I mentioned warned against fuses on negative iirc.

Comment: No, I’m asking _which_ 16 you are referring to. Please draw a schematic. Click edit and the schematic symbol.